# Default to current date range in combo box

Tags: sql, combobox, ms-access-2010, default-value

I have a combo box in which the values come from another table.  The list contains date spans, ie.  12/7/2014 to 12/14/2014, in date order.  The table that the values come from also have fields for the begin date (ie. 12/7/2014) and end date (12/14/2014).  To make it easier for the user, I would like to show the current date range as the default value in the combo box.  So, today, instead of going to 12/7/2014 to 12/14/2014, it would go to 1/18/2015 to 1/31/2015 - since today's date is 1/23/2015.  I am lost as how to do this.

The row source for the combobox is:  SELECT tblPayDates.DateSpan, tblPayDates.PayBegDate, tblPayDates.PayEndDate FROM tblPayDates

This is a SQL database with an Access front end.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!  I'm not even sure what to google.

Answer (score 0):

DateSpan appears to be your bound column, so you could get the range and set the combo to that.

A function

```
Function ThisFortnight()

    StartDate = Date - Weekday(Date, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
    EndDate = StartDate + 13

    ThisFortnight = StartDate & " to " & EndDate
End Function
```

Set the combo

```
Me.MyCombo = ThisFortnight
```

Comment: Does this just give me my combo box items?   I did it different than you, but my combo box works fine - it gives all the date spans (field datespan) from my table (table tblPayDates) in date order.  What I need is for the combo box to default to today's date range.  Now it goes to the first dates in the date range.

Comment: I forgot to type - Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not suggesting you change the existing combo row source, merely that you find the current range with the function and set the value of the combo to the current range, all the above is VBA. The function should be pasted into your module and the code can run in the Current Event of the form.